# Convert Integer to Timestamp in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two cloumns one of them is date(it is date format 2020-06-17), another one is time of transaction (it is integer 1258) how I can concat them as Timestamp?

Example

```
    Date    Time    Expected_Result
2020-06-17  1258    2020-06-17 12:58:00
2020-08-15  2315    2020-08-15 23:15:00
2020-10-10  1238    2020-10-10 12:38:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple approaches are possible. One would be convert everything to string first:

```
cast(cast(cast(d as format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as varchar(11))||' '||cast(cast(t as format '99:99') as varchar(10))||':00' as timestamp(0))
```

Another possibility is to split up hours and minutes using integer arithmetic and convert units individually:

```
cast(d as timestamp(0))+ (t/100)*interval '1' hour + (t mod 100)*interval '1' minute
```